# AAR ProGuard not obfuscating

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard

I have an AAR (library) project in Android Studio, to make a library we license.  I need to obfuscate the library we release to make it difficult for people to decompile.  But I can't seem to get the ProGuard to work.  When I unzip the AAR and then the "classes.jar" underneath, all the class names are still there as well as the variables.  I'm very weak at ProGuard usage, so wondering if the community can help.  I have an extremely basic ProGuard file, one that was generated when Android Studio created the template for the project:

```
-printmapping out.map
-keepparameternames
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
# -keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,EnclosingMethod
-keepattributes Exceptions

# Preserve all annotations.
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Preserve all public classes, and their public and protected fields and methods

-keep public class * {
    public protected *;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

probably it's too late but it could be helpful for anyone else.
I'm using this configuration and variables names are encrypted as well as parameters varialbes

```
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes Exceptions
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keep public class * {
    public protected *;
}
```

I'm also using this configuration in the build types so it's not debuggable

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
            zipAlignEnabled true
        }
    }
```

Let me know if it solved your problem or if you found a better solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
-keep,allowoptimization,allowobfuscation public class yourpackage.**
```

Comment: Please do not post only code as an answer, but also include an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality and are more likely to attract upvotes.